# ¿Como puedo iterar un JSONArray de objetos con un for each en JAVA?

Tags: java, json

Tengo el siguiente JSONArray en java y quiero recorrerlo con un `foreach`, no se si sea posible, gracias.

```
[{clave:valor,clave:valor,clave:valor},
 {clave:valor,clave:valor,clave:valor},
 {clave:valor,clave:valor,clave:valor},]
```

Answer (score 4):

Supongo que es esta [clase](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Podemos recuperar cada objeto para ver los valores

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    clave = object.getString("clave");        
}
```

Comment: En realidad la clase no pertenece a Android ni a Google sino a la implementación provista en [json.org](http://json.org/), específicamente a [esta librería](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer esto:

1. Sacar el array del objeto json:

   ```
   JSONObject json = //Mi objeto json
   JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) json.get("miObjeto");
   ```

   //suponiendo que lo tienes definido dentro de otro json ó

   ```
   JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
   ```
2. Iterar utilizando forEach:

   ```
   jsonArray.stream()
       .forEach(s -> {
               //ejecutar acciones aquí
           });
   ```